# How to hide settings on Google Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have created a google form. I want every time I open the form for editing, the setting will be hidden or disabled. Can you help me with this using a Google Apps Script or in some other efficient way.

Illustrating images

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The short answer is it's not possible by using Google Apps Script but might be possible by using a user-script or to develop a web-browser extension. If you need further help, please show add more details about the use case: is this is only for you or for others? are they part your your company or they could be anyone? Also add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Even if the trigger that executes a script when editing a form is available, a method that hides the setting tab is not available. If you can't do a certain thing on the Form UI itself, most likely that thing is not achievable/possible via script.

See more at [FormApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app)